# Are there advantages to using Adobe CC apps to create interactive content for AEM?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-animate, adobe, aem

My client recently moved to AEM and their website is now based on it. We have been asked to create an interactive HTML5 'component' (my term, not AEM's) to embed in a page.  In the past, we have created them using custom HTML5, but had a challenge integrating it into pages on the previous platform.

With my client's move to the AEM web platform, will the importing or placement of our HTML5 code and related files be quicker / easier / more compatible if we develop with an Adobe Creative Cloud app? For budget reasons, we are specifically looking to save development and integration time.

We have access to developers who know Adobe Animate CC, which is now targeted at developing interactive HTML / JavaScript content.  The other possibly relevant Adobe CC app would be Dreamweaver, but that is not something I would like to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: no, you won't save time.

When you want to create content for AEM, it should based on a component which gets integrated into a page's parsys. The best case scenario would be: you are provided with some hooks and integrate you component as a component using defined dependencies to avoid naming collisions etc when the JS and CSS is loaded.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I and the developers won't have the access to or knowledge of the AEM system.  We are only developing this interactive content, an applet or something similar.  We write it, they drop it on the page and it more or less just works.  I just want to know if content from the Adobe CC apps will integrate any faster or easier, or if any HTML5 development platform will do.

Comment: I don't think it will save time - especially if you don't have access to test your work.